# What is a good frugal method for providing shade to fruit-bearing vines?

Tags: pumpkins, shade

**What is a good and, hopefully, frugal solution for providing shade to long vines?**

In my case, I'm dealing with pumpkin vines on the ground.

I imagine a combination of sheets and chicken wire might do it, but I imagine chicken wire doesn't qualify as frugal.

Any ideas?

**Here's my layout**

[image]

Comment: can you please define "frugal" in your case? Shade cloth (fabric) is without doubt the best thing home gardeners can use in situations like yours. Shade cloth comes in variety of shade densities (you don't want to be blocking out too much of the sun). Shade cloth, if looked after will last for years, therefore making it a worthwhile investment...

Comment: I just used the word frugal to mean efficient in terms of money and effectiveness.

Comment: then I would look into shade cloth (like I said previously "if looked after will last for years, therefore making it a worthwhile investment") that offers 40% protection from the sun. Seeing as you're wanting to cover such a large area (large for the average home gardener) and also want to make it easily removable I would look into some kind of hooping system, or rig up something yourself with timber & support wires (rope).

Comment: @Mike - Like this, right? http://i.imgur.com/ubL4r.jpg

Comment: exactly! & that is a LOT! of shade cloth ;-)

Comment: hamlin11, Creating a Unique Shade Garden: http://web.extension.illinois.edu/podcasts/gc/201107_842.html -- Offers a nice approach, I think you could easily adapt to your needs...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have sheets to spare, so a temporary "clothesline" could to the trick. Drive in a few tall-ish stakes, get yourself some clothesline and clothespins from the hardware store (or some suitable rope if you have it laying around), and hang up sheets so they cast a shadow on your plants.

Just make sure you don't *completely* shade the plants -- they do need to get some light.